# Conditional Format Row based on IFERROR VLOOKUP result

Tags: vba, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditinally format every row that fails my IFERROR VLOOKUP formula in column A. I have gotten to where I can get the IFERROR cell to highlight, but not the entire now. Please help. This is what I have so far:

```
Range("A2:AH2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""Not VA Student"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: Do you really mean to apply for all rows from row 2 to bottom of sheet? This seems excessive? And are you only highlighting row where Not VA Student is found?

Comment: Yes, I am only trying to highlight rows where Not VA Student is found.

Comment: try code as per answer i posted. Chage sheet name as appropriate. Place in standard module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you meant by your IFERROR VLOOKUP as i can't see this in your code.

I think you are wanting to only highlight rows where "Not VA Student" is found in the stipulated range. Your current code does this for individual cells.

I think the range selected is likely excessive in that you select to the bottom of the sheet within the specified column limits.

Try the following. I have made minor amendments to existing code, credits to [user3598756](http://'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506700/finding-occurrences-in-order-vba)

```
Private Sub HighlightRows()

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim FoundCell As Range
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim FirstFound As String
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as appropriate

        Const fnd As String = "Not VA Student"

        With ws.Range("A2:AH" & ws.Range("AH2").End(xlDown).Row) '<--| reference the range to search into ''@qharr: this seems excessive to me

            Set FoundCell = .Find(what:=fnd, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count))  '<--| find the first cell

            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then 'Test to see if anything was found

                FirstFound = FoundCell.Address ' <--| store the first found cell address
                Set rng = FoundCell '<--| initialize the range collecting found cells. this to prevent first 'Union()' statement from failing due to 'rng' being 'Nothing'

                Do

                    Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)  'Add found cell to rng range variable

                    'Find next cell with fnd value
                    Set FoundCell = .FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
                Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound 'Loop until cycled through all finds

            End If

        End With

      If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 65535

End Sub
```